# Dynamically pushing instructions to SRAM IC

Tags: computers, ram

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this.  Coming from a programming background, and I'm not 100% sure how to read some of these data sheets.

I'm looking at using [IC 628512LP-70 CMOS SRAM"](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/157358BSI.pdf) (or comparable) in a "computer", on breadboards, that I'd like to build.  However, I'm wondering if this chip does what I'm understanding.

To my understanding, we've got 11 pins we can use to input memory to a buffer, which is then decoded, and placed into RAM.  We can then request that data by giving it the "buffer" (which I'd assumed would be its location in memory), and the RAM module gives us a "peek" at the data, which still remains in memory.

It would then be the microprocessor's job to manage that data and null them out if need be.

Is this the correct interpretation?  Am I using the correct chip?  Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: You would normally just use enable memory mapping, tell the processor to load parts of code from flash to external memory and tell it to execute it from there  and the processor deals with the rest. But why do you want to run from external SRAM? I also don't know how you got 11 pins. There are 30

Comment: You also refer to instructions in your title but data in your body. Please make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology is very wrong

- You do not "input memory to a buffer"
- You do not "request that data by giving it the "buffer""

This makes me fear that you are very much out of your depth here.

You read or write a memory. Static memories, as you have here, are the simplest to read and write. For that you have to connect the computers address and data bus to the chip's address and data bus. You will also need an address decoder to make the chip enable (not) signal.

Those signals have to follow the timing requirement as they are written down in the data sheet on the pages 4 to 7.

All the above require that you have access to a standard CPU bus with address, data and control lines. Most of the micro controllers these days do not bring those buses out. They are internal to the system.

Some have what is called a "secondary memory bus interface" which have the equivalent of these address, data and control lines. But I have never seen one with that many I/O pins (8 data, 17 address and 3 control lines.)

So answering your question means we have to design a complete memory interface system for you which is beyond the scope of this forum. (And we would need to know and study the processor you want to connect it to).

The best suggestion I can make is that you sit together with an experienced designer and ask him to guide you step-by-step through what is needed. **I expect this to take several hours.**

Comment: +1 for pointing out the incoherent terminology

Comment: For external RAM controllers... Some STM32s can have 16 data bits and 12+ address lines (I'd have to check the manual for exact value).

Comment: @JanDorniak 24 address lines I believe, plus control signals.Almost 48 in total.

Comment: @DKNguyen just checked... H7 allows up to 26 bits of address for SRAM and up to 13 address lines for SDRAM.

Answer (score 0):

> Coming from a programming background, and I'm not 100% sure how to
>   read some of these data sheets...

Words often have different meanings in different contexts, so the confusion is understandable.

> To my understanding, we've got 11 pins we can use to input memory to a
>   buffer, which is then decoded, and placed into RAM.

In digital circuits a 'buffer' may be a logic gate whose purpose is increase the strength of a signal line so it can drive more logic gate inputs. In your SRAM a buffer is necessary because the decoder stage has many gates with inputs connected to the address lines. Without buffers these inputs would put more load on the CPU address bus, reducing the number of devices that could be put on the bus. As a bonus the buffer can also create the inverted address bits that are required to decode some addresses.

In the block diagram of the SRAM we see that the row address buffer has 11 binary address inputs, and 22 outputs which are the normal and inverted address bits. These then go to the decoder which activates one of the 2048 rows in the memory array.

[image]

But to access an individual memory location the column must also be selected. This is done with the other 8 address lines which feed the column decoder. So all in all we have 19 address lines, which corresponds to 2<sup>19</sup> = 524288 unique memory locations.

The purpose of the address lines is simply to *select* a memory location in the array. Once this is done 8 bits of data can be written to the memory location or read out of it. The data transfer direction is controlled by /WE (Write Enable). If it is low when /CE (Chip Enable) is activated then whatever is on the data bus (usually data placed there by the CPU or DMA device during a write cycle) is written to the array. If /WE is high then data is read out of the array and put on the data bus (provided /OE, the data Output Enable signal, is also low).